# Multiple Select tag dropdowns inside while loop, but only retrieves data from the last one

Tags: javascript, php, html

Sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge and poor english, but I have a doubt that I'm pretty sure it's just a beginner's mistake.
I have a problem with the select tag inside a while loop. The thing is that I am creating an e-commerce shop about whey protein shakes and within it I created a page where I show different products, each product have different flavours (all of them have the same options)

I am retrieving all the products from my database, with a while loop.
And for each product, I tried putting a select tag, where I try to get the flavour by storing it in the "flavour" variable. For each product the webpage shows, there is a dropdown menu thanks to the select tag. However, the problem is that, only one dropdown table (the last one) is storing the value for the flavour. The ID of the different products are being stored correctly when the button is pressed, but not the flavour.

```
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM proteins ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
        ?>
            <div class="product">
                
                <div> 
                    <img class="img_product" src="products/proteins/<?=$r['image']?>"/>
                </div>
                
                <div class="name_product">
                    <?=$r['name']?>
                </div>
                <div class="precio">
                    <?=$r['price']?> <?=$coin?>
                                        
                    <?php
                        //only if user has logged in, can see the shopping cart button 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['id_client'])) {
                    ?>
                            //Button onclick to JS function, add to cart
                            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="addToCart('<?=$r['id']?>','flavour');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <?php
                        //If user hasn't logged in, they can't see the different flavours dropdowns
                        //In all different articles
                        if (isset($_SESSION['id_cliente'])) {
                    ?>
                            Flavour: 
                            <select id="flavour">
                                <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
                                <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
                                <option value="Cheesecake">Cheesecake</option>
                                <option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>
                                <option value="CookiesAndCream">CookiesAndCream</option>
                                <option value="Stracciatella">Stracciatella</option>
                            </select>
                    <?php
                        } 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function addToCart(productId, flavour) {

            var qty = prompt("Write product quantity",1);
            var selected = document.getElementById("flavour");
            var productFlavour = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value;

            if(qty.length>0) {
                window.location = "?p=proteins&add="+productId+"&qty="+qty+"&feature="+productFlavour;
            }
    }
</script>
```

Here's a visual example of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The HTML `id` attribute must be unique for each element, so you can't use the same value three times. You could use the product id maybe to make them each different:

```
<select id="flavour_<?= $r['id'] ?>">
```

Comment: And adjust the js selector: `var selected = document.getElementById("flavour_"+ productId);`

Comment: It is indeed unique, it retrieves with $r the PRIMARY KEY of that product, so it iterates through all products with their unique id's. So when you press the button, it retrieves its id correctly.

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant the product id, not the flavour id. You are right!

Comment: Alex Howansky and @IncredibleHat I tried your solution and it works perfectly, I never thought I'd get an answer this quickly with such ease. You two are masters, absolutely incredible.

Comment: @Angel hopefully your main take-away here is the importance of the `id` attribute in an HTML DOM needing to be unique. Its usually a first tripping point for coders. Next step, is migrating away from oldschool inline javascript things like `onclick` :D